# GS1-128 barcode parsing

Tags: barcode, barcode-scanner, barcode-printing, gs1-ai-syntax, gs1-128

Scanner Model :- Motorola- DS4208-HC

We need to parse the GS1-128 barcode. We know they are going to use GTIN(01), lot number(10), Expiration date(17), serial number (21).
Input String:- (01)07612345678900(17)100503(10)AC3453G3(21)455777

The problem is that barcode reader outputs a string, the format is like this:

01076123456789001710050310AC3453G321455777

Since there is not a separator and both serial number and lot number are a variable length according to GS1 standard, we have trouble to identify the segments.

There should be a FNC1 character at the end of a variable-length field that is not filled to maximum; so that FNC1 will appear between the G3 and the 21. what I have read is NC1 is invisible to humans but can be detected by scanners and will be reproduced in the string reported by the scanner. Simply send the string directly to a text file and examine the text with a hex reader. The FNC1 should be obvious. But we are still not able to read FNC1 in the reader.

Comment: The FNC1 character must be included for a variable-length field whether it is filled to maximum or not. The standards state that an FNC1 must be decoded as a GS control character (ASCII 29) when used as a field separator in GS1 Application Identifier Standard Format.

Comment: You should try generating known-correct GS1-128 symbols using the Online Barcode Generator (http://www.terryburton.co.uk/barcodewriter/generator/) and see what output your scanner generates. (This barcode generator accepts human-readable input to GS1-128 and will automatically place FNC1 characters into the encoded data as necessary.)  If you cannot see the GS characters when these symbols are scanned then you will need to fix/replace your scanning solution.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: @Neelam did you find a solution for this problem?

Comment: @nitintyagi If you have the same problem, why not improve the question, explain how you followed the answer provided by pfmaggi,and this might lead to a refined answer?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GS1 barcode parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25430823/gs1-barcode-parsing)

Answer (score 3):

Motorola Solutions Enterprise Business has been acquired by Zebra Technologies, so you can find support and developer forums on [Zebra website Launchpad](https://developer.zebra.com/community/technologies/advanced-data-capture).

[DS4208-HC support is available here](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/DS4208-HC_US-EN). However seems that most of the documentation/software are only available under the model [DS4208 support page](https://portal.motorolasolutions.com/Support/US-EN/Mobile+Networks+RFID+and+BarCode+Scanners/Bar+Code+Scanning/General+Purpose+Scanners/DS4208_US-EN)

To configure the scanner you can use the [123Scan2 utility](https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/ReleaseNotes/Customer-facing%20Release%20Notes%20for%20123Scan2.htm) or the [Scanner User Guide](https://atgsupportcentral.motorolasolutions.com/content/emb/docs/manuals/13923205a.pdf) where you can find the configuration barcodes to enable/disable GS1 decoding (page 9-27).

*Discalimer*: I work for Zebra Technologies.